# PHP json_encode() Emoji icons and letters as an array key value

Tags: php

I have an array which has Emoji icons and text strings as the key value, similar to below:

```
$a=array(
   " hi no 1"=> "  this is a test",
   " hi no 1"=> "  this is a test",
   " hi no 1"=> "  this is a test",
   " hi no 1"=> "  this is a test",
    " no 3" => array("this is a test"," test"),
    " no 3" => array("this is a test"," test"),
    " no 3" => array("this is a test"," test"),
    " no 3" => array("this is a test"," test"),
    " no 3" => array("this is a test"," test"),
);
```

The problem is that `file_put_contents($filepath,json_encode($a));` saves an empty array into the database. Would you suggest a solution?

Comment: What did [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg) say? What has `file_put_contents` to do with the database? What does that "empty array" actually look like?

Comment: Calling json_encode on $a and persisting it to a local file works for me without any error. Can you provide some more information around the problem you're having? Thanks!

Comment: it's not saving an empty file. It's saving the boolean FALSE which json_encode() returned, and false in a string context is a zero-length string.

Comment: See [Debugging JSON Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json/2637/debugging-json-errors) for how to debug it. Most likely the emoji are improperly encoded UTF-8

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
file_put_contents($filepath,json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

And see if that works, since emoji are unicode I would think that would solve it.